# How to show a continuous function from a space to a subspace is continuous from a space to the whole space?

Tags: general-topology, functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ and $(Y, \mathcal{J})$ be topological spaces. Let $W \subset Y$ be a subspace with its subspace topology.

> Show that if $f: X \to W$ is a continuous function, then $f: X \to Y$
>   is a continuous function. $f$ being the same function.

**Attempt:**

- We know that $f: X \to W$ is a continuous function, then $f^{-1}(V
     \cap W) \in \mathcal{T}, \forall V \in \mathcal{J}$
- Then $f^{-1}(V) \cap f^{-1}(W) \in \mathcal{T}, \forall V \in \mathcal{J}, W \subset Y$
- missing arguments
- Therefore $f^{-1}(V) \in \mathcal{T}, \forall V \in \mathcal{J}
     \Leftrightarrow f: X \to Y$ is continuous

How should I fill the missing argument to argue that $f^{-1}(V) \cap f^{-1}(W) \in \mathcal{T} \implies f^{-1}(V) \in \mathcal{T}$?

Comment: $f^{-1}(W) = X$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ be an open subset of $Y$, $U\cap W$ is open in $W$, thus $f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(U\cap W)$ is open.